# Why does SQL Server require non-clustered index to use unique keys?

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332982/do-clustered-indexes-have-to-be-unique

The answer is **yes**. In the sense that SQL Server will make it unique by appending 4-bytes to key. This makes sense given that clustered index is used for data addressing purposes (Correct?).

According to my research, it seems that SQL Server **requires non-clustered indexes to be unique as well**. And when non-unique column is used, SQL Server appends a 4-byte "uniquefier" value to make it unique. Is that correct?

Why does SQL Server require non-clustered index to use unique keys?

Comment: So it can locate the row in the index. Just because a non-clustered index might not have its own unique key, and in fact two rows may be indistinguishable for *you*, SQL Server still needs to be able to tell two rows apart.

Comment: I understand the "locator" problem. But representation could be as simple as:
(non-unique-value) -> [locator1, locator2, locator3]

rather than:
[(non-unique-value+4bytes, locator1), (non-unique-value+4bytes, locator2), (non-unique-value+4bytes, locator3)].

That's the bit I don't get.

Comment: About nonclustered: on leaf level clustered index key is stored (with 4-bytes appendix if applied). Thus if you make clustered index non-unique, you must account that physical key will be 4 bytes bigger and every non-clustered index will require additional space for it too.

Comment: I guess you could consider designing your own system with simpler  representation. In the meantime, this is how SQL Server works.

Comment: As Aaron said, *this is how SQL Server works*. Other DBMSes might do it differently, e.g. a Non-Unique Secondary Index in the Teradata DBMS stores the data the way you wanted:  *index value -> array of ROWIDs for this value* :-)

Comment: If there were multiple locators for each non-unique value the internal table holding this information would break 1NF. One of Codd's rules for a relational system is that it should manage itself relationally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably it simplifies the engine a lot because you can now address individual rows.

Imagine, you are indexing on a `IsMale bit` column and there are 1 million "male" values. Now you want to address exactly one of those rows to delete it. The index has 1 million rows that just say `true` and nothing more. I'm sure it's possible but uniqueness makes the design much more elegant.

Locking requires index rows to be uniquely identifiable.

Comment: IMHO, it makes implementation horribly inefficient (I am sure that's NOT the case though).
Intuitively, I'd expect IsMale bit to be represented twice (True, False) and each value pointing to a list of pointers to on the CLUSTERED INDEX. Why that's not the case?

Comment: This is not how b-trees work in SQL Server. An index (b-tree) is just a copy of the base table with a subset of columns and sorted differently. It's a "sorted list". This is a rather nice and general model because all indexes are the same. SQL Server does not distinguish (in a a relevant way) between CI and NCI on a physical level.

Comment: What you propose is theoretically possible. It would be a form of data compression built into the b-tree. The space savings depend on how big index prefixes typically are.

Comment: Locking... that was the bit I oversaw.

Comment: Imagine your scenario of a "list of pointers pointing to the clustered index". If I did ANY sort of physical address change, I'd have to update those pointers or they'd be invalid. This means even if there wasn't a data change to the CI the NCIs would all have to be updated. That's horribly inefficient and the basis of how heaps work. In fact, heaps have forwarding/forwarded records to cut down on exactly that issue.